# Yii2 UUID not mapped with model value

Tags: yii2, uuid, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components, yii2-user

I am using `p2made/yii2-uuid:` * this extension to generate UUID
     to get UUID

```
 $varUuid = \p2made\helpers\Uuid\UuidHelpers::uuid();
 mapping uuid to model--->
 $model->expenses = $varUuid;
```

if i `echo $model->expenses` it shows uuid but if i print $model->expenses it
     is  converted to object i cant to send to API..
     how can i do this i need to send uuid  with model field with uuid value?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the actual UUID value to `expenses` field this way.

```
$model->expenses = $varUuid->toString();
```

The helper file that you utilised are extending from [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid).
You can view the usage examples [here](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid#examples).